# TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am running this query and on **puts** I am getting an error **TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer** if I just try to get the ID from the array.

**puts billing_ids** then the output is `[<Billing id: 66, date: "2019-11-31", created_at: "2019-04-22 22:28:23", updated_at: "2020-01-15 17:03:05">]`

And if I do **puts "#{billing_ids["id"]}"** to get just the id then I get the error **TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer**

Please help me figure out how can I get the ID.

```
Office.all.each do |office|
  billing_ids=[] #initialize array
  office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
    billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id #add id to array
  end
  puts "#{billing_ids["id"]}"
end
```

Output

```
[#<Billing id: 66, date: "2019-11-31", created_at: "2019-04-22 22:28:23", updated_at: "2020-01-15 17:03:05">]
```

Comment: can you just do `puts billing_ids` and post the output here

Comment: @gautam output added

Comment: What do you want to accomplish ? print all Billing ids in a string ?

Comment: can you even use " insids " ? after " , I think one quotation must be used? look syntax error ?

Comment: @Navroop You should do `billing_ids.map(&:id)` as your `billing_ids` array has objects and not just ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to print the ids of the objects which are in a Array.

Try this: `puts "{billing_ids.map(&:id)}"`

About the error **TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer**

The error is because you are tring to access an index "id" of an `Array` of Billing objects. The `id` attribute of a particular object can be obtained but if you try accessing `id` of the Array, thats not going to work. (Note `billing_ids` is an Array as per your code). Array can be accessed by indices which are integers (unlike `Hash`)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing billing_ids as an empty array and then pushing a billing model ID (an int) into it. If you do billing_ids.first you will then get the ID you're fetching in: `issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id`.

So try `puts "#{billing_ids.first}"`.  This should get your ID.

Note: the `<<` operator appends—pushes the given object on to the end of the array, and since you are pushing an ID, not a billing model into billing_ids, you cannot access the model property ['ID'] of an ID.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.id` this line to `billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.billing.id` OR `billing_ids << issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date).order(:date).last.pluck(:id)`